# Can you disengage past multiple enemies with no opportunity attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, opportunity-attack

During my turn I want to attack two enemies that are in different areas using my movement.Can I disengage with a bonus action past multiple enemies without triggering an opportunity attack?

Comment: Is there anything more to this? how are you gaining disengage as a bonus action?

Comment: Given what Drew points out, are you playing either a rogue or a goblin or something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The disengage action states:

> If you take the Disengage action, your movement doesn't provoke opportunity attacks for the rest of the turn.

Seems pretty self explanatory. It doesn't say to choose one creature to not provoke opportunity attacks from, it just says your movement doesn't provoke opportunity attacks. So if you take the disengage action, you don't provoke opportunity attacks from any creature for the rest of your turn.

Comment: It might be worth highlighting that because it is an action as standard the OP's suggestion of moving and attacking won't work unless they have something that allows disengage as a bonus action.